# How to predict with a “getTree” tree

Tags: r, binary-tree, random-forest, prediction

I have a random forest model. With `getTree` function I can get all trees created in my random forest Model. Now I want to check the predictions made by each tree for some observations. For this reason I need to make prediction using each tree of my random forest Model.

I found this question with the same objective. But, unfortunately, this question has not been answered.

[https://stackoverflow.com/q/40875489/3834837](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875489/r-randomforest-how-to-predict-with-a-gettree-tree)

Any propositions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the `randomForest` package then you can do this by using `predict(...,predict.all=T)`, which would get you all the predictions for each tree. Then you can select whichever you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So, I get  the individual matrix (predict$individual)  and I'am wondering if the colmn index corresponds to the real index of the tree in the forest? I mean, did the colmn index can be used  in the getTree function to get the right tree (getTree (rfModel, k= index))?

Comment: @Mouaici_Med Yes, the columns represent the individual trees, you should get the same tree if you use the index from predict on getTree.